# How to implement pagination using jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, pagination

I want to do pagination for my search result page.
I have two hyperlinks `Previous` and `Next` for showing the all search results. when my page loads first time I want to make `Previous` disable and on clicking on `Next` I want to make it available. and when page reaches last page i want to disable `Next` this time and in the same way when `Previous` reaches 1st page want to disable it. How can i achieve this using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of this ready made plug-in http://webdesign14.com/15-best-jquery-table/
**EDIT:**
Create one table from your search results with `id=my_table"` (just for example or you can use any other id) and use following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#my_table').dataTable();
   } );
</script>
```

Just make sure you add jquery.js and other required js in your file.

Comment: Ajinkya : I did not get which one is of my use. and how can i use it. please help me.

Comment: Ajinkya: ya i checked it. its working exactly as i want but how i use it in my page. wht i need to do. i mean i don't know how to use plug-ins.

Comment: To look the effect i created a table and use it as u said. please check  http://jsfiddle.net/bhXbh/45/  but i am not getting pagination here.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#data_table').dataTable( {
                "aaData": dataSet,
                "aaSorting": [[0,'asc'],[0,'desc'],[2,'asc'],[2,'desc'],[3,'asc'],[3,'desc'],[4,'asc'],[4,'desc'],[5,'asc'],[5,'desc'],[6,'asc'],[6,'desc'],[7,'asc'],[7,'desc']],
                "iDisplayLength": 4,                
                "bInfo": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",//this is used for pagination with nos and first , next , last , preivous
                "sPageButton": "paginate_button",
                "sPageButtonActive": "paginate_active",
                "sPageButtonStaticDisabled": "paginate_buttond",
                "bAutoWidth": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                    {   "sTitle": "Seller",
                        "sWidth": "50px",
                        "sClass": "grey" ,
                        "fnRender": function(obj) {
                            var data = obj.aData[ obj.iDataColumn ];
                            return "<A href='"+ data.url +"'>"+ data.title +"</A>";
                        }

                    }
]
})
```